# Set caption font size for figures in YAML header of Rmarkdown

Tags: r, yaml, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am using Rstudios markdown to write a report which I would like to compile to pdf using latex as well as to html...

Is it somehow possible to adjust the size of caption fonts for images included in an `![caption](figure.jpg)` environment? At the moment captions in html look like the rest of the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control this with css. For instance:

```
<style type="text/css">
.caption {
    font-size: x-small;
}
</style>

![caption](figure.jpg)
```

See css guides such as [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp) for the available `font-size` options.

Answer (score 10):

This answer has obviously already been accepted but just for completeness I am adding the PDF aspect of the question.

If you wish to alter the caption font size for your PDF documents I would recommend to use the `caption` package via one of the following two approaches:

***header-includes* - option:**

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Jorge Luis Borges"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[font={small}]{caption}
output:
  pdf_document
---
```

The focus here is on `font={<font options>}`.

***in_header* - option:**

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Jorge Luis Borges"
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: style.tex
---
```

Where `style.tex` is included in the same directory that contains the .Rmd file. The `style.tex` file needs to contain `\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}`.

As before, the focus here is on `font={<font options>}`.

---

With the `caption` package you have loads of customisation options, just to name a few, see below:

- `scriptsize` = very small size
- `footnotesize` = size typically used for footnotes
- `small` = small size
- `large` = large size
- `it` = italics
- `bf` = bold face

For full reference please visit the [official documentation](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf).

Also, some cross-references here to articles on the TexSE site:

[Change the font of figure captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/822/change-the-font-of-figure-captions)

[How to include Latex package in RMarkdown](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171711/how-to-include-latex-package-in-r-markdown)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Johnny's earlier comment, I wanted a bit more modification to my figure caption in my pdf report. I wanted a caption to look like the following:

> ***Figure 1***. This is a graph to explain productivity.

To get this, add in YAML:

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[font={small,it}, labelfont={bf}]{caption}
output:
  pdf_document
---
```